# How to reference external sbt project from another sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following setup of a Scala application and a common core library:
root

```
 -> /ApplicationA
   -> /project
     -> /build.sbt
 -> /CoreLibrary
   -> /project
     -> /build.sbt
```

I want to add a reference from ApplicationA to CoreLibrary à la Eclipse project reference, so that every time CoreLibrary changes ApplicationA is built as well. I´ve tried the following contents of build.Scala for ApplicationA:

```
  val core = Project(
      id = "platform-core",
      base = file("../CoreLibrary"))

  val main = Project(id = "application, base = file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```

However, when compiling ApplicationA SBT complains that a dependency can only be a subdirectory!!:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Directory C:\git\CoreLibrary is not contained in build root C:\git\ApplicationA
```

This seems completely straightforward, what's the correct way of having this project dependency?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do a source dependency on your project like that :

```
 lazy val core = RootProject(file("../CoreLibrary"))

 val main = Project(id = "application", base = file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```

I have a working example with a multimodule play build : https://github.com/ahoy-jon/play2MultiModule/blob/master/playapp/project/Build.scala

But I think the proper way (it depends of your context) of doing it is to create a

```
 -> /project/
   -> Build.scala
 -> /ApplicationA
   -> /project
     -> /build.sbt
 -> /CoreLibrary
   -> /project
     -> /build.sbt
```

referencing the two projects and the dependencies between them.

Comment: The first approach worked perfectly! Thanks! Had to use RootProject :)
The problem with the second approach is that they are 2 github repos, so to have them work you would need an extra one on top or something

Comment: @Diego See git submodule for an easy way to have separate git repos under a single, outer, git repo.

Comment: The so-called "proper way" is a poor solution IMO. You shouldn't need a container project to declare dependency between two siblings.

Comment: they are not siblings because they are not seen in the same parent root.

Comment: The link to the example is dead.

Comment: What if project depends on two sub-projects? Two RootProject elements allowed?

Answer (score 23):

With sbt 0.12.1 it seems possible to get a simple reference to a project :

I used `ProjectRef` instead of `RootProject`

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/api/sbt/ProjectRef.html

```
ProjectRef(file("../util-library"), "util-library")
```

sbt-eclipse also works.

Comment: Excellent! But only works if the subproject uses the same version of Scala.

Answer (score 13):

Since **sbt 0.13**, you may create multi-project definitions directly in `.sbt` without needing a `Build.scala` file.

So adding the following to  **ApplicationA/project/build.sbt** would be sufficient.

```
lazy val core = RootProject(file("../CoreLibrary"))

val main = Project(id = "application", base = file(".")).dependsOn(core)
```