# How to set up multi-module build with reference to external local sbt project?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I just started with Scala and Play and I'm trying to set up a multi build with sbt 0.13.5
My project structure is the following:

```
/AnormCypher
   -> /src
      ->/main
        ->/scala
          ->org.anormcypher[package]
              ->[Some classes]
   -> [other dirs/files]
   -> build.sbt
/sample
   -> /src
      ->/main
        ->/scala
          ->/controllers[package]
              ->Application.scala
              ->[Some classes]
   -> [other dirs/files]
   -> build.sbt
```

The sample project depends on the AnormCypher project. I tried to set up the dependency following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653435/how-to-reference-external-sbt-project-from-another-sbt-project). My build.sbt in sample looks like this:

```
name := """sample"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)

lazy val core = ProjectRef(file("../AnormCypher"), "anormcypher")

val main = root.dependsOn(core)
```

When I go into my console and type

```
activator
```

sbt is able to load the project. But when I try to compile the sources and try to use classes from the org.anormcypher package, they can't be resolved:

```
object anormcypher is not a member of package org
[error] import org.anormcypher._
[error]            ^
```

Running a `clean compile` also brought no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

to

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(core)
```

and remove

```
val main = root.dependsOn(core)
```

`reload` and the project should work fine.