# Library dependencies with AnormCypher

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, neo4j, anormcypher

I would like to use AnormCypher in my Scala project (with SBT).

I am not using Play! Framework. Can I use AnormCypher anyway?

If yes, how can I install the library. There is no .jar file or something.

As the official github page said, I added

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "anormcypher" at "http://repo.anormcypher.org/",
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.anormcypher" %% "anormcypher" % "0.6.0"
)
```

to my build.sbt.

But Intellij produces `Unresolved Dependencies errors`.

I am new to scala and neo4j and I am seriously lost. If someone can help and tell me what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: Just to comment, you need to be running scala 2.11.x for this. You don't need to use play.

Comment: Error is 

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.anormcypher#anormcypher_2.10;0.60: not found

And my version of Scala is 2.11.4

Do I have to link a library or do something other?

Comment: It's trying to include the 2.10 version of the lib, so it looks like your intellij is using scala 2.10. Maybe if you specify scala 2.11 in your sbt build file, that would work?

Comment: @WesFreeman it works (I added "scalaVersion := "2.11.4"" to my build file) but it produces a new error. 

"object anormcypher is not a member of package org"

I tried to follow this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262952/how-to-set-up-multi-module-build-with-reference-to-external-local-sbt-project but I don't use Play Framework so it does not work.

Comment: I add a clarification (@WesFreeman) : Anormcypher is well integrated in external libraries of the project (image) : 

http://simplifiedbmx.fr/img/anorm.JPG

Comment: Can you add the code where you're importing anormcypher? Seems like that's where the problem is now.

Comment: The only thing I did is to change my build.sbt to 

`name := "clustContextsSBTV2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "anormcypher" at "http://repo.anormcypher.org/",
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.anormcypher" %% "anormcypher" % "0.6.0"
)`

I tried to unzip anorm project and add the main directory to depedencies (via F4 -> dependencies -> add -> directory or JAR) but, it changed nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have any code using anormcypher yet?

Comment: This is difficult to debug in tiny comments. Can we continue the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/anormcypher

Comment: Of cource, I created a subject here :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/anormcypher/SjlWd2mL1CY

Comment: My solution was to install Intellij 14 instead of Intellij 13. If it can help!