# shapeless port to scala-js: create artifact with few external dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, shapeless, scala.js

There is a port of shapeless library to scala-js (https://github.com/alexander-myltsev/shapeless). I need to publish artifact properly with fewer possible dependencies to original shapeless.

Now I forked Miles Sabin's repo, and added changes required to generate scala-js library: add scalajs-sbt-plugin, tune build.scala, add bintray-sbt-plugin.

It is wrong to ask shapeless maintainers to merge my branch because scala-js could broke their build.

On the other hand I'd like to have minimal dependencies to original repo as well. Theoretically and ideally what I'd like is to create, say, shapeless-scalajs sbt-project from scratch. Then reference somehow original shapeless library. And then derive from shapeless-build-scala with required overrides to build it against scala-js and publish to my bintray.

I believe in almighty sbt :) What are my options to solve this task?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this was discussed in [shapeless's github issue tracker](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/100) and at Scala Days, and everyone concluded that a fork was the right way to go. Now we just need to decide the best way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is (no sbt hackery involved):

1. Fork shapeless
2. Create Scala.js branch
3. Change build files as you need. That is, modify the `shapelessCore` project directly as in your PR. (add `scalaJSSettings`, your repo coordinates)
4. Commit
5. Publish shapeless to your maven central
6. When a new version of shapeless comes out, just merge shapeless/master with your scala.js branch. If no changes happened to the build file, this will merge just fine.
7. Re-publish

This will be way easier than an sbt project that depends on an external project (which is [doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653435/how-to-reference-external-sbt-project-from-another-sbt-project), but doesn't directly allow you to reuse settings etc.)

Comment: +1. This is more or less how I maintain shapeless's 2.10.x branch relative to with master (which is on Scala 2.11.x). The delta in that case is a lot bigger than what you're proposing here, nevertheless git handles the repeated merges and extremely smoothly.

Comment: Uh, oh... That means you'll need a scala.js-2.10 branch, too.

Comment: @gzm0, of course this is a solution! I am doing it now in that exact way. I hope you don't mind if I leave this question to fish SBT-hack solution.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I'd be interested in an sbt-solution, too.

Comment: guys any progress on shapeless port to scala.js ?