# How create properties (variables) in sbt which are reusable across builds?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

With maven I can create a parent `pom.xml` and extends it everywhere. Also in parent pom I can define some general properties like library version and other properties which are wanted to share across several imdepeneded projects. How to do this with sbt if projects are **different** and they do **not** build from one root project/folder?

**Important**

The question is not about multi project build!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but should work:

1. Create a normal SBT project, define your desired settings, etc. there. Let's say it's in the path `~/parent`.
2. Note that the `project` folder of an SBT project is *itself* a project.
3. You can [depend on external projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653435/how-to-reference-external-sbt-project-from-another-sbt-project) from file system or VCS in SBT. In the builds where you want to reuse parent project, create `project/project/Build.scala` (or `project/build.sbt`) if it doesn't exist yet, define the project as usual and and add a dependency on `ProjectRef(file("~/parent"), "project")`.

Comment: Project ref can also point to an url so you might even be able to reference a common config that isn't put inside the project.

Comment: I did say that you can have a VCS (Git, etc.) URL, but yes, I could have mentioned that it doesn't have to be in your file system in step 1 as well.