# In SBT, how to reference a subproject of another project?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT it is possible to [depend directly on another project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653913/371739). This has the advantage that when running `~compile`, a change to the dependency causes a rebuild.

Now I want to depend on a subproject of another project, without depending on any of its siblings. So, for example, I have:

```
a/
    build.sbt
    b/
        build.sbt
    c/
        build.sbt

d/
    build.sbt
```

and I want `d` to depend on `b` but *not* on `c`.

I tried, in `d/build.sbt`,

```
lazy val d = ProjectRef(file("../a"), "b")

lazy val root = project.dependsOn(d)
```

but this gives

```
Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
    com.foo:a_2.10:1.0
      +- root:root_2.10:1.0
```

I could of course do

```
lazy val d = RootProject(file("../a/b"))
```

except that it is possible for `a/build.sbt` to contain additional settings for `a/b` that won't be pickup up this way. I need a reference that will pick up `a/build.sbt` but also refer specifically to `a/b`.

Is there any way to make this sort of reference?

Answer (score 2):

It was just a stupid mistake on my part.

```
lazy val root = project
```

is not correct. That line of code creates a subproject in a directory called `root/`. [The correct way to refer to the root project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653913/371739) is:

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
```

after that,

```
lazy val d = ProjectRef(file("../a"), "b")

lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).dependsOn(d)
```

works as it should.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I have a `Dependencies` object in `Dependencies.scala` under `project` and as soon as I use `ProjectRef` sbt can't find what is defined in there any more.

Comment: @rabejens Interesting, it sounds almost like maybe your `dependsOn` in `build.sbt` is overriding it? Maybe you could define your dependencies in `Dependencies.scala` as a variable that you could refer to from `build.sbt` so you could add both sets in one place?