# Import code packaged as jar into another sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to import below code packaged as jar to another sbt intellij project how could i do this?

```
package yyy

object Hello extends Greeting with App {
  println(greeting)
}

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello"
}
```

Comment: I would recommend, you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653435/how-to-reference-external-sbt-project-from-another-sbt-project . this will allow you to update your original source and not worry about building jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this code packaged as a jar, you can simply place it in the `lib/` folder of the other sbt project. It should be on the classpath, so you'll be able to do `import yyy._` in the code.

You can read more about [unmanaged dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies) in the sbt documentation. Here's an excerpt from it:

> Unmanaged dependencies work like this: add jars to `lib` and they will be placed on the project classpath. Not much else to it!
>
> Dependencies in lib go on all the classpaths (for `compile`, `test`, `run`, and `console`).
>
> There’s nothing to add to `build.sbt` to use unmanaged dependencies, though you could change the `unmanagedBase` key if you’d like to use a different directory rather than `lib`.

Comment: i had done that but its not working. I'm using sbt 1.0.0. I tried everything that could be done .First i created lib folder (not actually present before) and placed in it jar file.But while doing import its not picking it up.

Comment: You should add all the details about what you've tried and how it didn't work to the question. What do you mean by "its not picking it up"?

Comment: I mean import yyy._ simple doesn't work.I created lib folder placed jar in it but the import doesn't work.

Comment: You will have to provide more details about your setup, otherwise I cannot help you. Add your `build.sbt` and any other relevant details to the question. Also describe how you're using the project and what errors do you get. You should also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve